# Can graphs have isolated vertices?

Tags: data-structures

Can a graph have an isolated vertex without edges?

Would this count as 1 graph or 2?

[image: graph]

Comment: This depends on your data model and your definition of a "graph". What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @cplusplusrat I'm trying to understand if all the vertices in a graph need at least one edge when the size is larger than 1.

Comment: Look up isolated vertex here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory)

Comment: Yes. It can have isolated vertex. But if you count the connected components, then it will have two connected components.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a graph is that it is just an ordered pair of a vertex set say V and an edge set say E, where E is a subset of VxV .

There is no restriction saying that every vertex should have atleast one edge.

Of course we can have local definitions to solve a particular problem, but generally what you drew is just a single graph with 2 connected components.